# Installing freetds for Python Virtual Environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, freetds, pymssql

I've set up a basic Python3 virtual environment and need access to an SQL server, however I can't seem to find out how to have pymssql module locate the freetds install in the virtual environment. My dir structure is:

```
VirtualEnv/
    --------.git/
    --------(git files)
    --------bin/
              -------activate
              -------easy_install
              -------pip
              -------python3
              -------(more bin stuff)
    --------include/
    --------lib/--> python3.5 --> site_packages --> (modules & sources)
    --------project_dir/--> (project sources)
```

Where do I place the freetds module and point pymssql to it?

Comment: The FreeTDS `.so` binary lives at the system level, outside of your `virtualenv`. What distro are you using? You're going to need to install some pre-requisites. Ubuntu? CentOS?

Comment: Im running on a MAC so I'm assuming its BSD. The virtual environment is the distribution that comes packaged with Python3. Is there a way to install the freetds packages in this virtual environment?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get it running locally on your Mac, your best bet is to install FreeTDS via homebrew. It'll be installed on a system level, and then either pyodbc or pymssql can use FreeTDS to communicate with SQL Server.

First install homebrew:

http://brew.sh/

Then install FreeTDS:

```
brew install freetds
```

Then test connecting to the server over FreeTDS:

```
tsql -H <yourdbhost> -p <yourdbport> -U <yourusername> -P <yourpassword>
```

From there, take the same credentials and connect with pymssql in Python. Good luck!

Comment: The issue arrises since I am running python3 in a virtualenv, but my freetds is located at the system level. It seems I need the virtualenv to either look outside itself to find the freetds files or I need to install freetds and whatever dependencies on the virtualenv, the latter being what I feel is the best way.

Comment: The virtualenv should only affect Python and its packages, not anything on the system level. To verify this, try running `tsql -C` and `which tsql` with no virtualenv, and then with one activated.